# Conducting music written in 6/8

Tags: performing

Can I get an illustration on how a choir master can conduct a piece of music written in 6/8 time? Thanks.

Comment: Like Tim  said, conducting in 2 is most common although there is a 6 pattern, it would have to be a slow tempo to conduct all those beats. Scroll down on this page to see it: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/musicappreciation_with_theory/chapter/conducting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 6/8 is essentially two time, down up works just fine. Each movement will encompass three quavers, so instead of counting 1 2 3 4 5 6, the count will be **1**(2 3) **2**(2 3).

If it's incredibly slow, there could be an opportunity to count two lots of three, but that would be unusual.

Comment: Also if it’s fast enough it could be conducted in one.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - condutors can't conduct in one, I believe. Their hand/arm needs to return to the top of the beat before the next downstroke! So isn't that two..?

Comment: The difference between conducting in one and in two is that in two, the hand or point of the baton crosses the imaginary line twice - once on the down stroke and again on the up stroke, and there’s usually a kind of bounce or pause at the bottom. In one is more of a continuous motion and the beat is at the bottom of the stroke. There’s a video of Leonard Bernstein demonstrating it on YouTube. Fast waltzes like the Blue Danube are often conducted in one.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - ah, that's what I envisaged when I wrote down up. Down = 1st beat, up = 2nd. So each bar used two movements, down, then up. So the last 'beat is an upbeat/upstroke, just like in 3/4 and 4/4 time.

Comment: Conducting in two and conducting in one are two different things. Maybe I’ll find a link for you to look at later today. Conducting is based on a horizontal beat line. Each time the baton hits or crosses the line is a beat. In one the baton only touches the line once per measure and then goes back up. In two the baton hits the line on the downbeat and crosses it again on the upbeat.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - thanks for piquing my interest in conducting! It seems there are many ways that are used for conducting 6/8, really the only similarities being down is always 1, and the upbeat at bar's end is always shown with upward movement. I'll continue my foray into conducting...

Comment: It's not really Down-Up.  It's a low position 'click' then a high position one.   Think knocking on a door waist-height and then shoulder-height.  Sort of.  You can do a string of low knocks, lifting the arm in preparation for each.  That's one-in-the-bar conducting.  (Again, sort of.)  Conducting is more than elementary 'beating time'.

Comment: Conducting on one is not really recommended. It is usually much better to switch to conducting phrases and not measures. For example if every phrase consists of four 6/8 measures, you conduct like 4/4 with one swing for every measure. It is much clearer. However sometimes you cannot avoid conducting on one. (And it is a great tool, if you are lost during difficult polyphony. To change to one-beat conducting.)

Answer (score 3):

In conducting course I attended, we were taught four patterns. It depends on tempo and which beats are stressed.

1. If the tempo is fast and 1st and 4th beats are stressed, you conduct like 2/4 (on the stressed beats).
2. If the tempo is fast and 1st, 3rd and 5th beats are stressed, you conduct like 3/4 (on the stressed beats).
3. If the tempo is slow and 1st and 4th beats are stressed, you conduct every beat in this way: down (and outside), inside, inside, outside, outside, up.
4. If the tempo is slow and 1st, 3rd and 5th beats are stressed, you conduct every beat in this way: down (and inside), inside, outside, outside, inside (and slightly up), up. (It is like 3/4, but you make two beats in one direction.)

Of course, there are also different patterns, but for rare situations.

Comment: Isn't 6/8 time where the 1st, 3rd, and 5th beats are emphasized really 3/4 time?

Comment: I second this. If it isn't in two, it isn't 6/8.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Yes and no. Similarily I could ask, If 6/8 with 1st and 4th beats emphasised isn't really 2/4 with triplets. I assume you speak about fast tempo, because in slow tempo, 3/4 and 6/8 are different things.
If you conduct 6/8, it often happens that some beats are 1,4-emphasised and some 1,3,5-empasised. Consider main theme of America from West Side Story (https://youtu.be/JioV6kI316I?t=59). It is fast tempo and the stresses are constantly moving. You would conduct odd measures with the first pattern and even measures with the second pattern.

Comment: @VitHenych - "America" from *West Side Story* was probably always going to be a tough one to notate and conduct. If I'm not concerned with bringing out accents, I'd probably conduct strictly according to the sheet music. This often means not changing conducting patterns. (I've seen other questionably notated ensemble sheet music such as Michael Markowski's *Shadow Rituals*. That one has several measures notated as alternating 4/4 and 3/4 time that all recordings play as 7/8 time instead.)

Comment: @VitHenych - Regarding your "Similarily I could ask, If 6/8 with 1st and 4th beats emphasised isn't really 2/4 with triplets.", you could very well be right - I've actually seen the same music notated both ways, and in those cases, I'd truly play both of them the same way and not strongly question either notation upon listening to recordings. This is unlike "6/8 time" with beats 1, 3, and 5 emphasized - keep those beats emphasized for too many measures in a row and I'm likely to leave a comment on your piece asking you to re-notate the excerpt in 3/4 time.

Comment: @VitHenych - In fact, I could have sworn that I've seen music notated as 4/4 time with triplets that you could argue should be notated in 12/8 time instead. Looks like 6/8 is truly a notational convenience, while 4/4 time is so common that it might actually be debatable whether 4/4 time with triplets or 12/8 time is easier to read.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Well, I was taught, that conduct strictly according to the sheet music means actually changing the patterns, since it is how the author wrote the accents. But I guess that different teachers have different approaches. The thing is, you can actually find 3/4 music according to you, written like 6/8 however. And for this music, you use the second pattern (to make it 3/4). I think we agree to each other.

Answer (score 0):

In concert band, I've seen slow 6/8 time - or slow 6/4 time - conducted like 4/4 time, except with an extra flick of the hand at Beats "2" and "3" of the 4/4 conducting pattern. The conducting pattern for slow 6/8 time therefore looks like this from your point of view:

Down -> Left -> Flick -> Right -> Flick -> Up

Fast 6/8 ended up getting conducted like 2/4 time, except with the "upstrokes" of 2/4 time being transferred to beats 3 and 6 of 6/8 time.

I have no reason to believe that choir masters conduct differently, especially since I've also been in 2 school choirs.

Comment: If anything, from my experience, choir masters conduct *less* often than concert band conductors.